# Manga with female lead who got thrown into parallel world and is able to escape that world after years

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm searching for a manga in which the female lead is thrown off a cliff into a demon/bad world as a child and is able to survive. After she escapes she becomes the vassal of the leader of a nation or army and helps the kingdom defeat the demon lords in that parallel world. One of the lords is a snake and teleports her into a garden with the male lead. He is also the leader of a group of fighters and helps her fight inside the rift. Her father is the leader of another division and tries to kill her but doesn't succeed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?